# Custom characters to replace standard keyboard input

Tags: character-encoding

I have made my own language which I intend to use in a project(novel/game). This language also has letters from `a` to `z` with some variations then and there. However they look different, you can imagine them as characters from Kanji, Klingon, etc.

I want to be able to type this language on a Windows machine. Now, I don't know which angle I want to approach this in because I'm not well versed in this at all.

1. Should I make my own windows language pack? If so how? How can I map specific symbols to keystrokes?
2. Should I somehow add them into Unicode (not officially), or somehow make my own custom character encoding, maybe copy ASCII and then just replace the symbols? Is that even feasible? Extended ASCII?

I want to be able to type the symbols anywhere, not just word for example. I also need the characters to work in my IDE (to put in strings and so on). And I just need it to work on my own machine.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Pretty broad, and needs clearer specs. Is your made-up language (Kobaïan, it's Kobaïan, right?) constructed of letters, or pictograms, or some other kind of grapheme? How many are there? Do they change based on context? Is this like Wingdings? Then of course you can make a font load it into whatever environment you need it in. If you need that quick, switching batch and forth functionality that you can get with different keyboard layouts, then research that. My advice is to start with more clearly defining your needs, then do some research, and ask more specific questions.

Comment: It's my own language. There is a symbol that I made up for every existing letter. By loading a font, what do you mean? Can you elaborate on that? From what I know now, I will scan all of my symbols (letters) so they can be in a digital format. On that note, do I need a specific format to load the font? I imagine it's not as simple as loading a JPEG.

Comment: I realize it's hard to read tone online, so apologize for that. By loading a font, I mean, you create a font, and then you load it where you need it. Much like how you load any other font into the software you want to use it in (word, photoshop, your browser, etc) https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+create+a+font&oq=how+to+create+a+font